# Making an object move back and forth in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an unit move from left to right and then back again in a endless loop, but I can't seem to get it to work it only moves left and then doesn't move at all.

What I currently have is

```
var q = 10;
var m = 130;
var stepx = 1.55;
```

for drawing the object:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(goalieX, goalieY, goalieWidth, goalieHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

and within the draw function there's this which moves the object left but not right

```
 if(m > 105 && m != 180) {
     m -= stepx;
   }
   else if (m <= 105 && m != 180) {
     m += stepx;

   }
   m += dm;
   q += dq;
```

why doesn't the object move back right?

Comment: Can you post an animated example?

Comment: Instead of `m -= stepx` and `m += stepx` you would always use `m += stepx` and toggle the sign of `stepx` (`stepx = -stepx`) as soon as the object leaves the boundaries.

Comment: @FrancoScarpa Here's a jsfiddle of the entire thing: https://jsfiddle.net/b5z9y8Lq/3/

Comment: @t.niese would you mind doing a more accurate change representation? I don't quite know how to implement that.

Comment: @Veraen the linked question and its answer, show (at least if I have understand your problem correctly) two running examples how to do it. Beside that you already doing the exact same thing the ball in your code using the `dx` variable.

Comment: @t.niese ah you were right I managed to fix it using the link you gave me, thank you for the help.